# Type Member w/ Implicit

Tags: scala, implicit

Given:

```
// type-class
trait Eq[A]

class MyInt 
object MyInt {
  implicit val myIntEq = new Eq[MyInt] {}
}

sealed trait Something {
  type A 
  implicit val x: Eq[A]
}

case object SomethingImpl extends Something {
  override type A = MyInt
  override implicit val x = MyInt.myIntEq
}
```

Then, I used the type member's `implicit` via:

```
scala> def f(s: Something): Eq[s.A] = {
     |   implicit val x: Eq[s.A] = s.x
     |   x
     | }
f: (s: Something)Eq[s.A]
```

However, my instincts tell me that it's somewhat clumsy to have to bring the implicit into scope via `implicit val ...`.

Perhaps I should define the `f` function within the `Something`'s companion object?

What's the standard way to define this `f` function?

Comment: Your example of `f` function seems to be over-simplified, because with the current information, I would simply implement it as `= s.x`.

Comment: You can `import s.x`.

Comment: @Jasper-M That's the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bring a certain implicit into scope, you usually `import` it.

```
def f(s: Something) = {
  import s.x
  ???
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write `f` in the `Something` companion? I tried, `object Something { def f(x: Something) = {
    implicitly[Eq[x.A]];
    ???
  }
}`, but that did not compile.